# Is setting every node style anchor compatible with relative positioning in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I'm trying to create a diagram and would like my nodes left aligned using the `anchor=west` option. I'd prefer to use relative positioning to make my diagram more flexible to changes. Here's my example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  every node/.style = {anchor=west}]

\node[fill=red!40, draw] (n0) at (0,0) {Base node} ;
\node[fill=red!40, draw] (n1) at (0,-2) {Node with longer text} ;
\node[fill=red!40, draw] (n2) [below=of n1] {Node with even longer text} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice how the second node uses the `anchor=west` style set for every node, but the third node with the longest text seems to be centered below the second vs. being left aligned with it. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Essentially, I want the alignment of the second node without having to specify absolute coordinates.

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking I answered my own question. Found this as I was scanning the manual: `If you use relative coordinates together with automatic anchor coordinates, the relative coordinates are computed relative to the node's center, not relative to the border point.` If there's a way to do this (like override the setting, or use some automatic math to adjust based on half the width of each node...), I'd still like to know.

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63469/3235

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  every node/.style = {anchor=west}]

\node[fill=red!40, draw] (n0) at (0,0) {Base node} ;
\node[fill=red!40, draw] (n1) at (0,-2) {Node with longer text} ;
\node[fill=red!40, draw] (n2) [below=of n1.west, right] {Node with even longer text} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## from de pgfmanual:

16.5.2 Basic Placement Options

Unfortunately, while perfectly logical, it is often rather counter-intuitive that in order to place a node above a given point, you need to specify the south anchor. For this reason, there are some useful options that allow you to select the standard anchors more intuitively:

`/tikz/above`  (default 0pt)

Does the same as anchor=south. If the  is specified, the node is additionally shifted upwards by the given .

```
above \tikz \fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[above] {above};

above \tikz \fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[above=2pt] {above};
```

`/tikz/below=<offset>`(default 0pt)
Similar to above.

`/tikz/left=<offset>` (default 0pt)
Similar to above.

`/tikz/right=<offset>` (default 0pt)
Similar to above.

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing? I didn't see the right alignment in the TikZ manual for all of the relative positioning options... looks like it works, though!

Comment: So `above` sets the anchor to `.south` and `right` sets it to `.west`, correct? And this puts it below `node.west` and sets the anchor of the node being placed to `.west` as well. I'm still not entirely grasping passing multiple placement options, and didn't see them combined in the manual, but nevertheless, this is definitely what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Implicitly, `below` implies `anchor=north` (and with `below=of n1`, the reference is `n1.south`), `left` implies `anchor=east`, etc.

An example (blue node shows that default reference is not `n1.center`, lime node shows the desired positioning):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=west}]

\node[fill=red!40, draw] (n0) at (0,0) {Base node} ;
\node[fill=red!40, draw] (n1) at (0,-2) {Node with longer text} ;

\node[fill=red!40, draw,below=of n1] (n2) {Node with even longer text} ;

\node[fill=blue!40, draw,below=of n1.center] (n2) {Node with even longer text} 

\node[fill=lime!40, draw,below=of n1.south west,anchor=north west]
 (n2) {Node with even longer text} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, the answer is "No," right? I have to set the anchor for each node manually since it's overridden by `below=of...`?

Comment: @Hendy you can easily define a style to factorize your positioning rule. But you are right: `anchor` and `positioning` are not independent...