# How to start a new line when drawing a finite state machine using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tree-like diagram (flow chart?) showing selection of scientific papers when reviewing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/tree-like-diagram-flow-chart-showing-selection-of-scientific-papers-when-revi)

I am trying to draw a state using tikz.

The state I want to use draw is:

```
\node[state]    (A)   {Wait for 0 from below};
```

The problem is: What can I do if I want "Wait for 0 from below", showed in two lines, like this:

```
Wait for 0
from below
```

This code does not work:

```
\node[state]    (A)    {Wait for 0 \linebreak from below};
```

Comment: Add `text width=xx cm` to your node options maybe with `align=center` for the alignment of text.

Comment: @percusse Sorry, I am a newbie, could explain more about it?

Comment: Sure, try changing that line to `\node[state,text width=1.8cm]    (A)   {Wait for 0 from below};`. If you want to align the text at the center use the extra option in my previous comment. By the way, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Next time, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem such that we can help more definitely as we will know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Thank you @percusse, it works pretty well, thank you very much. But can I break those lines manual?

Comment: Yes, those options tell TikZ to respect the line breaks so regular \`\\\` works.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Because if this solves the problem it's a duplicate. I'll try to find the proper one.

Comment: The issue is explained roughly in the answers of this [Tree-like diagram (flow chart?) showing selection of scientific papers when reviewing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/tree-like-diagram-flow-chart-showing-selection-of-scientific-papers-when-revi)