# drawing arrows with coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, arrows

I'm trying to draw arrows with coordinates so that they don't go through existing nodes but I'm not able to. Is there any parameter to indicate the arrow coordinate (this is my first draw using Tikz btw, so I'm kinda newbie yet)?

This is my current draw and code, I'd like to add arrows like the green ones:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sigma demostration draw}
\author{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={($(current page.west)+(5.5cm,-3cm)$)}]
 % flecha
 [->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1cm,font=\scriptsize]
 % estilo circulo
 \tikzstyle{circulo}=[circle,fill=cyan,draw=none,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=9mm]
 % estilo cuadrado
 \tikzstyle{cuadrado}=[rectangle,fill=blue,draw=none,text=black,draw=blue!40, fill=blue!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=11mm]
  % estilo cuadrado pequeño
 \tikzstyle{cuadrado2}=[rectangle,fill=blue,draw=none,text=black,draw=blue!40, fill=blue!10, very thick, minimum size=3mm, minimum width=7mm, minimum height=5mm]
  % estilo elipse
 \tikzstyle{elipse}=[rectangle,rounded corners=8,fill=cyan,draw=none,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm]
 % cuadrado transparente
 \tikzstyle{transparente}=[rectangle,fill=white,draw=none,text=black,minimum size=6mm]

% G1
\node[cuadrado] (g1_1) {$(y_m)$};
\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left = 1cm of g1_1] {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_3) [right = 1cm of g1_1] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_4) [above left = 0.5cm of g1_2] {$y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_6) [above right = 0.5cm of g1_3] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_8) [above right = 0.5cm of g1_2] {$[y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_9) [above left = 0.5cm of g1_3] {$[\neg y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_10) [above = 0.5cm of g1_8] {$[y_m^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_11) [above = 0.5cm of g1_9] {$[\neg y_m^1]$};

% G2
\node[cuadrado] (g2_1) [above = 3cm of g1_1] {$(y_1)$};
\node[circulo] (g2_2) [left = 1cm of g2_1] {$y_1$};
\node[circulo] (g2_3) [right = 1cm of g2_1] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_4) [above left = 0.5cm of g2_2] {$y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_6) [above right = 0.5cm of g2_3] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_8) [above right = 0.5cm of g2_2] {$[y_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_9) [above left = 0.5cm of g2_3] {$[\neg y_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_10) [above = 0.5cm of g2_8] {$[y_1^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_11) [above = 0.5cm of g2_9] {$[\neg y_1^1]$};

% G3
\node[cuadrado] (g3_1) [above = 8cm of g1_1] {$(x_n)$};
\node[circulo] (g3_2) [left = 1cm of g3_1] {$x_n$};
\node[circulo] (g3_3) [right = 1cm of g3_1] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_4) [above left = 0.5cm of g3_2] {$x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_5) [below left = 0.5cm of g3_2] {$\langle x_n\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_6) [above right = 0.5cm of g3_3] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_7) [below right = 0.5cm of g3_3] {$\langle \neg x_n\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_8) [above right = 0.5cm of g3_2] {$[x_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_9) [above left = 0.5cm of g3_3] {$[\neg x_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_10) [above = 0.5cm of g3_8] {$[x_m^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_11) [above = 0.5cm of g3_9] {$[\neg x_m^1]$};

% G4
\node[cuadrado] (g4_1) [above = 12cm of g1_1] {$(x_1)$};
\node[circulo] (g4_2) [left = 1cm of g4_1] {$x_1$};
\node[circulo] (g4_3) [right = 1cm of g4_1] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_4) [above left = 0.5cm of g4_2] {$x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_5) [below left = 0.5cm of g4_2] {$\langle x_1\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_6) [above right = 0.5cm of g4_3] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_7) [below right = 0.5cm of g4_3] {$\langle\neg x_1\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_8) [above right = 0.5cm of g4_2] {$[x_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_9) [above left = 0.5cm of g4_3] {$[\neg x_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_10) [above = 0.5cm of g4_8] {$[x_1^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_11) [above = 0.5cm of g4_9] {$[\neg x_1^1]$};

% G10
\node[circulo] (g10_1) [below = 1.5cm of g1_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_2) [below left = 0.6cm of g10_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_3) [below right = 0.6cm of g10_1] {$u_0 \_ u_0^,$};
\node[circulo] (g10_4) [below = 1.2cm of g10_1] {$u_0^,$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_5) [below left = 0.6cm of g10_4] {$u_0^,$};


% G5
\node[elipse] (g5_1) [right = 1.4cm of g4_7] {$\thinspace x_1 \vee\neg x_n\vee y_1$};
\node[transparente] (g20_1) [right = 1cm of g5_1] {$\dotsb$};
\node[circulo] (g5_2) [right = 2.4cm of g5_1] {$c_i$};
\node[transparente] (g20_2) [right = 0.8cm of g5_2] {$\dotsb$};
\node[circulo] (g5_3) [right = 2.2cm of g5_2] {$c_k$};
\node[transparente] (g5_4) [above left = 0.7cm of g5_2] {$\dotsb$};
\node[transparente] (g5_5) [above = 0.7cm of g5_2] {$\dotsb$};
\node[transparente] (g5_6) [above right = 0.7cm of g5_2] {$\dotsb$};
\node[transparente] (g5_7) [above left = 0.7cm of g5_3] {$\dotsb$};
\node[transparente] (g5_8) [above = 0.7cm of g5_3] {$\dotsb$};
\node[transparente] (g5_9) [above right = 0.7cm of g5_3] {$\dotsb$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g5_10) [below = 0.4cm of g5_1] {$[c_1]$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g5_11) [below right = 0.5cm of g5_1] {$[c_1]$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g5_12) [below left = 0.5cm of g5_2] {$[c_i]$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g5_13) [below right = 0.5cm of g5_2] {$[c_i]$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g5_14) [below left = 0.5cm of g5_3] {$[c_k]$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g5_15) [below right = 0.5cm of g5_3] {$[c_k]$};

% G6
\node[circulo] (g6_1) [below = 3cm of g5_2] {$all$};
\node[cuadrado] (g6_2) [below left = 1cm of g6_1] {$u_0 \_ all$};
\node[cuadrado] (g6_3) [below right = 1cm of g6_1] {$all \_ all^,$};
\node[circulo] (g6_4) [below = 1cm of g6_3] {$all^,$};
\node[cuadrado] (g6_5) [below = 1cm of g6_4] {$all^,$};
\node[cuadrado] (g6_6) [right = 1cm of g6_1] {$all$};

% G7
\node[circulo] (g7_1) [below = 14cm of g5_12] {$col_i$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_2) [above right = 0.3cm of g7_1] {$col_i$};
\node[transparente] (g70_1) [below = 1cm of g7_1] {$\dotsb$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_6) [left = 0.1cm of g70_1] {$[\neg x_1^k]$};
\node[transparente] (g70_2) [left = 0.03cm of g7_6] {$\dotsb$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_5) [left = 0.1cm of g70_2] {$[\neg x_1^1]$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_4) [left = 0.3cm of g7_5] {$[x_1^k]$};
\node[transparente] (g70_3) [left = 0cm of g7_4] {$\dotsb$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_3) [left = 0cm of g70_3] {$[x_1^1]$};
% --------------------------
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_7) [right = 0.1cm of g70_1] {$[y_m^1]$};
\node[transparente] (g70_4) [right = 0.07cm of g7_7] {$\dotsb$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_8) [right = 0.7cm of g7_7] {$[y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_9) [right = 0.1cm of g7_8] {$[\neg y_m^1]$};
\node[transparente] (g70_5) [right = 0.07cm of g7_9] {$\dotsb$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g7_10) [right = 0.7cm of g7_9] {$[\neg y_m^k]$};

% G8
\node[circulo] (g8_1) [below = 13cm of g5_1] {$col_1$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g8_2) [above right = 0.5cm of g8_1] {$col_1$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g8_3) [above left = 0.5cm of g8_1] {$ ? $};
\node[cuadrado2] (g8_4) [below left = 0.9cm of g8_1] {$ ? $};
\node[cuadrado2] (g8_5) [below right = 0.9cm of g8_1] {$ ? $};
\node[transparente] (g80_1) [above = 0.2cm of g8_1] {$\dotsb$};
\node[transparente] (g80_2) [below = 0.5cm of g8_1] {$\dotsb$};

% G9
\node[circulo] (g9_1) [below = 13cm of g5_3] {$col_n{}_+{}_m$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g9_2) [above right = 0.6cm of g9_1] {$col_n{}_+{}_m$};
\node[cuadrado2] (g9_3) [above left = 0.6cm of g9_1] {$ ? $};
\node[cuadrado2] (g9_4) [below left = 0.4cm of g9_1] {$ ? $};
\node[cuadrado2] (g9_5) [below right = 0.4cm of g9_1] {$ ? $};
\node[transparente] (g90_1) [above = 0.2cm of g9_1] {$\dotsb$};
\node[transparente] (g90_2) [below = 0.1cm of g9_1] {$\dotsb$};


\path   
% G1
    (g1_2) 
        edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_10)
    (g1_3) 
        edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_11)
% G2
    (g2_2) 
        edge [below] node {k} (g2_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g2_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_10)
    (g2_3) 
        edge [below] node {k} (g2_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g2_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_11)
% G3
    (g3_2) 
        edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_10)
    (g3_3) 
        edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_11)
% G4
    (g4_2) 
        edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g4_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.2] node {1} (g4_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_10)
    (g4_3) 
        edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g4_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.2] node {1} (g4_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_11)
% G10
    (g10_1) 
        edge [above  left, pos=0.5] node {k+1} (g10_2)
        edge [above  right, pos=0.5] node {n} (g10_3)
    (g10_4) 
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {n+2} (g10_3)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {k} (g10_5)
% G5
    (g5_1)  
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {M-1} (g5_10)
        edge [above right, pos=0.7] node {M-1} (g5_11)
    (g5_2)  
        edge [right, pos=0.8] node {2n-2} (g5_4)
        edge [right, pos=0.6] node {2n-2} (g5_5)
        edge [right, pos=0.4] node {2n-2} (g5_6)
        edge [above left, pos=0.7] node {M-1} (g5_12)
        edge [above right, pos=0.7] node {M-1} (g5_13)
    (g5_3)  
        edge [right, pos=0.8] node {2n-2} (g5_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.6] node {2n-2} (g5_8)
        edge [right, pos=0.4] node {2n-2} (g5_9)
        edge [above left, pos=0.7] node {M-1} (g5_14)
        edge [above right, pos=0.7] node {M-1} (g5_15)
% G6
    (g6_1)  
        edge [above left, pos=0.6] node {1} (g6_2)
        edge [above right, pos=0.6] node {k+3} (g6_3)
        edge [above, pos=0.5] node {n} (g6_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g5_11)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g5_13)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g5_15)
    (g6_4)  
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {3M} (g6_3)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {M} (g6_5)
% G7  
    (g7_1) 
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {n} (g7_2)
        edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g7_3)
        edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g7_4)
        edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g7_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.7] node {1} (g7_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.7] node {1} (g7_7)
        edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g7_8)
        edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g7_9)
        edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g7_10)
        %edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g5_10)
        %edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g5_12)
        %edge [above, pos=0.85] node {1} (g5_14)

% G8
    (g8_1) 
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {n} (g8_2)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g8_3)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g8_4)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g8_5)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g80_1)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g80_2)
  
% G9
    (g9_1) 
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {n} (g9_2) 
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g9_3)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g9_4)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g9_5)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g90_1)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {} (g90_2)
        
    ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Besides that, I don't understand why the arrows don't appear. Is there a problem with this line?

```
 [->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1cm,font=\scriptsize]
```

And a small doubt I have is about writing a line break inside a node. The node in red I would like it to look like this:

[image]

How can I make it show "c1" at the top and the rest of the clause at the bottom?

Comment: for your question regarding the linebreak this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/tree-like-diagram-flow-chart-showing-selection-of-scientific-papers-when-revi/63469#63469) should solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your need to clean up your code a bit. There are some redundant definitions such as `fill=cyan,draw=none,draw=cyan!40,fill=cyan!10`. The last definition will always precede, so you can delete the first one.

Then, you may want to use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` (although there may be some dispute about which one is better, I think that using `\tikzset` has become the standard). Furthermore, you need to assign your style to something. You cannot simply write `[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt]` since this does not belong to anything. You need to tell Ti*k*Z to which elements it should apply this definition. This has already been done for the other styles such as `circulo`, `cuadrado` etc.

In order to draw arrows, you can use the `\draw` macro and connect the different nodes, more or less like it has already been done for the black lines.

You already load the `shapes` library which comes with a real ellipse node. You can make use of this. In order to enter a line break inside a node, you need to set an alignment to this node.

Below is a shortened example that uses parts of your code to help you get started.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzset{
 % flecha
 flecha/.style={->,>=stealth',green!50!black,shorten >=1pt}, 
 % estilo circulo
 circulo/.style={circle,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=9mm}, 
 % estilo cuadrado
 cuadrado/.style={rectangle,text=black,draw=blue!40, fill=blue!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=11mm}, 
 % estilo cuadrado pequeño
 cuadrado2/.style={cuadrado, minimum size=3mm, minimum width=7mm, minimum height=5mm}, 
 % estilo elipse
 elipse/.style={rectangle,rounded corners=8,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm}, 
 % elipse real
 elipse2/.style={ellipse,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm, inner sep=1pt}, 
 % cuadrado transparente
 transparente/.style={rectangle,fill=white,draw=none,text=black,minimum size=6mm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%[remember picture,overlay,shift={($(current page.west)+(5.5cm,-3cm)$)}]

% G1
\node[cuadrado] (g1_1) {$(y_m)$};
\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left = 1cm of g1_1] {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_3) [right = 1cm of g1_1] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_4) [above left = 0.5cm of g1_2] {$y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_6) [above right = 0.5cm of g1_3] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_8) [above right = 0.5cm of g1_2] {$[y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_9) [above left = 0.5cm of g1_3] {$[\neg y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_10) [above = 0.5cm of g1_8] {$[y_m^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_11) [above = 0.5cm of g1_9] {$[\neg y_m^1]$};

% G3
\node[cuadrado] (g3_1) [above = 8cm of g1_1] {$(x_n)$};
\node[circulo] (g3_2) [left = 1cm of g3_1] {$x_n$};
\node[circulo] (g3_3) [right = 1cm of g3_1] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_4) [above left = 0.5cm of g3_2] {$x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_5) [below left = 0.5cm of g3_2] {$\langle x_n\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_6) [above right = 0.5cm of g3_3] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_7) [below right = 0.5cm of g3_3] {$\langle \neg x_n\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_8) [above right = 0.5cm of g3_2] {$[x_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_9) [above left = 0.5cm of g3_3] {$[\neg x_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_10) [above = 0.5cm of g3_8] {$[x_m^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_11) [above = 0.5cm of g3_9] {$[\neg x_m^1]$};

% G10
\node[circulo] (g10_1) [below = 1.5cm of g1_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_2) [below left = 0.6cm of g10_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_3) [below right = 0.6cm of g10_1] {$u_0 \_ u_0^,$};
\node[circulo] (g10_4) [below = 1.2cm of g10_1] {$u_0^,$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_5) [below left = 0.6cm of g10_4] {$u_0^,$};

%%%
\node[elipse, align=center] (g5_1) [below = 2cm of g3_1] {$C_1$ \\ $\thinspace x_1 \vee\neg x_n\vee y_1$};

\node[elipse2, align=center] (g5_1) [below = 3.5cm of g3_1] {$C_1$ \\ $\thinspace x_1 \vee\neg x_n\vee y_1$};

\path   
% G1
    (g1_2) 
        edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_10)
    (g1_3) 
        edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_11)
% G3
    (g3_2) 
        edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_10)
    (g3_3) 
        edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_11)
% G10
    (g10_1) 
        edge [above  left, pos=0.5] node {k+1} (g10_2)
        edge [above  right, pos=0.5] node {n} (g10_3)
    (g10_4) 
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {n+2} (g10_3)
        edge [below right, pos=0.5] node {k} (g10_5);

\draw[flecha] (g3_5) -- ++(-1,-1) |- (g10_1);
\draw[flecha] (g3_7) -- ++(1,-1) |- (g10_1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, there were many things I didn't know. Why my arrows don't appear as arrows but as lines (the arrowhead is missing)? Talking about this line: `[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1cm,font=\scriptsize]` is anything missing?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve with this line. Do you want to define options generally for the whole `tikzpicture`? Then you need to combine it with the other general options like `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={($(current page.west)+(5.5cm,-3cm)$)}, ->, >=stealth', shorten >=1pt, node distance=1cm, font=\scriptsize]`. The option `auto` makes no sense to me. This way, all the lines should get arrow heads. Is this what you want?

Comment: Oh, I see... Yes, was that. I really appreciate you help. Thanks!