# TikZ positioning: is it possible to use arithmetics?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like for the blue box (`text3`) to be below the other two boxes and to have the width of the other two boxes together. So basically I want to make the blue box (the large one in `%Row2`) wider without messing with the width measurements. Would that be possible?

Something like `below=of node1 and node2` would do the trick but I haven't figured out a way to do it.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  SmallBox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=#1!20, minimum width=8em, align=center, minimum height=3em},
  LargeBox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=#1!20, minimum width=8em,align=center, minimum height=3em}
]

\matrix[row sep=0.5em]
{
  % row 1
  \node {}; & \node (cell32) {}; & \node {}; & \node (cell34) {}; & \node {}; & \node {}; \\

  % row 2
  \node {}; &
  \node {}; &
  \node {\tikz{
      \node [SmallBox={red}] (node1) {text1};
      \node [SmallBox={green}, right=of node1] (node2) {text2};
      \node [LargeBox={blue}, below=of node2] (node3) {text3};
  }}; &
  \node {}; &
  \node {}; &
  \node {}; \\
};

% horizontal line
\draw [thick] (cell32.east) -- (cell34.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `fit` to create a node which encloses the required nodes, and then the `let`..`in` syntax to get that node width. Also you can omit the `fit` node and measure instead the width of the desired nodes and add them inside the `let`..`in` construct.

Comment: You can also have a look to the macro `\CalcDistance` in [Replicate this chart using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103760/replicate-this-chart-using-latex/103816#103816), even if in this case maybe the `fit` library is simpler.

Comment: How does the vertical line above all nodes fit in the picture here? Is it simply a horizontal line that should appear at the top of the whole picture or is it a content of the construct of nodes. For the first, the `backgrounds` library already provides the right tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fit` library for width selection. I've added:

- `fit,calc` for `\usetikzlibrary`.
- `fit={(node1) (node2)},yshift=-1em` to "set" the width and move it a bit down.
- `inner sep=0pt`.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  SmallBox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=#1!20, minimum width=8em, align=center, minimum height=3em},
  LargeBox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=#1!20, minimum width=8em,align=center, minimum height=3em}
]

\matrix[row sep=0.5em]
{
  % row 1
  \node {}; & \node (cell32) {}; & \node {}; & \node (cell34) {}; & \node {}; & \node {}; \\

  % row 2
  \node {}; &
  \node {}; &
  \node {\tikz{
      \node [SmallBox={red}] (node1) {text1};
      \node [SmallBox={green}, right=of node1] (node2) {text2};
      \node [LargeBox={blue}, below=of node2,fit={(node1) (node2)},inner sep=0pt,yshift=-1em] (node3) {text3};
  }}; &
  \node {}; &
  \node {}; &
  \node {}; \\
};

% horizontal line
\draw [thick] (cell32.east) -- (cell34.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: resulting pic]

Comment: If you need `calc` library only for the shifts you can use `([yshift=-1em]...)` without loading it.

Comment: I managed to adjust the text3 vertical height with `text height=1.8em`.

Comment: @Daniel (and m0nhawk) The `fit` library uses `text width` and more importantly `text height` and `text depth` to “fit” the content (this is also the reason why the inner seps still matter). The vertical space is evenly divided to the height and the depth. The baseline is thus vertically centered. I’d avoid this with either my solution or using a `label=center:text3` which places a label with its anchor (default: center) at the center anchor of the node. (Obviously, the node will not stretch with the content then, but I guess that’s what you wanted anyway.)

Answer (score 5):

another solution that does not require use of a matrix or calculation, only fif bookstores and positionning

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  SmallBox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=#1!20, minimum width=8em, align=center, minimum height=3em},
  LargeBox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=#1!20, minimum width=8em,align=center, minimum height=3em}
]

      \node [SmallBox={red}] (node1) {text1};
      \node [SmallBox={green},below  right=of node1] (node2) {text2};

\node[fit=(node1) (node2),inner sep=0](node12) {};

\coordinate[below=3em of node12.south west]  (left);
\coordinate[below=3em of node12.south east]  (right);

  \node [LargeBox={blue},fit=(left) (right), inner sep =0 ] (node3) {text3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

some comments

[image]

the line

```
\node[fit=(node1) (node2),inner sep=0](node12) {};
```

determine the minimum size of the node that supports the other node with fit and inner sep=0

the last node is constructed after positioning two points in the right and left ends, again using

```
\coordinate[below=3em of node12.south west]  (left);
\coordinate[below=3em of node12.south east]  (right);

  \node [LargeBox={blue},fit=(left) (right), inner sep =0 ] (node3) {text3};
```

Answer (score 4):

The original `fit` key is not really suited for nodes that shall contain text and be placed differently (or should only inherit the height or the width). This can be seen in both currently existing answers where `text3` is slightly shifted upwards because `fit` internally sets the keys `text width`, `text height` and `text depth`. This is also the reasons the `inner sep` need to set to zero. Actually the `outer sep`s also need to be considered. More on this has been observed in [TikZ: Make node height span several others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124371/16595).

The internals of the `fit` library though are great to scan any number of nodes/coordinates. The code of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124507/16595) to the linked question extend the `positioning` library and combines it with the `fit` library. It has been combined in my [`positioning-plus`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex) library.

It makes it possible to simply write

```
\node [SmallBox=red]                       (n1) {Text 1};
\node [SmallBox=green, right=of n1]        (n2) {Text 2};
\node [LargeBox=blue,  below=of -(n1)(n2)] (n3) {Text 3};
```

The `-` in the value to the `below` key marks the following node(s) to be used as a reference in the width of the created node (but with the `inner xsep`s active). This is something similar to your idea of using `below=of n1 and n2`. The height of the third node could also be smaller than that of the other nodes.

The random horizontal line is also drawn in relation with the upper nodes. The starred version of `xshift` and `yshift` use the already established `node distance`s as a factor. The same applies for the usual `positioning` keys that are prepended by one or two factors (separated by `and`) delimited by a colon `:`. The factors used here are `.25` for the *x* direction and `1` for the *y* direction.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning-plus}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  SmallBox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=#1!20, minimum width=8em, align=center, minimum height=3em},
  LargeBox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=#1!20, minimum width=8em, align=center, minimum height=3em},
  node distance=+.5em and +1cm
]

\node [SmallBox=red]                       (n1) {Text 1};
\node [SmallBox=green, right=of n1]        (n2) {Text 2};
\node [LargeBox=blue,  below=of -(n1)(n2)] (n3) {Text 3};

\coordinate[above left=1 and .25:of n1]  (pLine1);
\coordinate[above right=1 and .25:of n2] (pLine2);
\draw[red,thick] (pLine1) -- (pLine2);

\draw ([xshift*=-.25,yshift*]n1.north west) -- ([xshift*=.25,yshift*]n2.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I retrieved `tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code` from the link supplied, but when I ran the code here (using freshly updated MacTeX2017),  I received this error: `./positioning-plus_ex.tex:18: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.18 \draw ([xshift*=-.25,yshift*]n1.north west)
                                                 -- ([xshift*=.25,yshift*]n2...`

Comment: Later: If I hit `Return`, I get the error again. If I hit `Return` a second time, the correctly (?) typeset output appears.