# How to create following block diagram structure in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, tikz-styles

[image: Cascading Blocks]

How can i create this kind of connected and cascading block diagram in Latex?

Comment: This is one for Tikz. Will post an answer.

Comment: I would use the package `schemabloc`...
Working on an example...

Comment: Downvoted.  It seems the question is very localized, I can see no effort on the author's side, and - please tell me if I'm nitpicky, but could people asking questions here learn how to spell LaTeX?

Comment: Hi, Pratap, you might show some effort with [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) on your part in terms of attempting a solution, which will motivate others and reduce downvotes. @mbork may be give him a benefit of doubt due to newuser tolerance and brought box answer.

Comment: OK, forgive me.  Maybe I'm just in a bad mood.  I'm undoing my downvote.

Comment: @mbork - Point duly noted. Will keep in mind while posting questions in future.

Comment: Also related: [Replicate this chart using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103760/13304) where one just has to remove the arrows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you can specify the width of the boxes (it will be adjusted to fit if too short) and the separation between the boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{cascading}{width}{\cascading@wd=#1}
\define@key{cascading}{sep}{\def\cascading@sep{#1}}
\newdimen\cascading@wd

\newcommand{\cascadingblocks}[2][]{%
  \setkeys{cascading}{sep=2ex,#1}%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \@for\next:=#2\do{%
      \settowidth{\dimen@}{\next}%
      \ifdim\dimen@>\cascading@wd
        \cascading@wd=\dimen@
      \fi
    }%
    \@for\next:=#2\do{%
      \cascading@rule
      \hbox{\fbox{\hb@xt@\cascading@wd{\hss\next\hss}}}%
    }
  }
}
\def\cascading@rule{%
  \def\cascading@rule{%
    \hb@xt@\dimexpr\cascading@wd+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule\relax
      {\hss\vrule\@height\cascading@sep\hss}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% natural width, default sep
\cascadingblocks{foo,bar,foobar,foobazzzz}
% 3cm width, 3pt sep
\cascadingblocks[width=3cm,sep=3pt]{foo,bar,foobar,foobazzzz}
% 1cm width (automatically increased), default sep
\cascadingblocks[width=1cm]{foo,bar,foobar,foobazzzz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as the stick-it-in-a-sty-and-forget-it quality goes, this is a winner.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}
\lineskip0pt

\framebox[3cm]{\strut Text1}

\makebox[3cm]{\strut\vrule}

\framebox[3cm]{\strut Text2}

\makebox[3cm]{\strut\vrule}

\framebox[3cm]{\strut Text3}




\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought about the `picture` environment, but the simplicity of this is astonishing;).

Comment: tsk-tsk-tsk... after your first TikZ answer, I thought you had renounced to the bad habit of making thing simple ;-)

Comment: @david How to reduce the space between the two blocks?

Comment: Haha, now things get less simple;).  I'd try deleting `\strut` and play with `\vrule height 6pt` etc. - though this is not the LaTeX way;).

Comment: @PratapDheeraj as mbork said (or use \rule{1pt}{6pt} as a latex alternative) If you make it less that baselineskip you may need to set `\baselineskip` to 0pt as well as `\lineskip`. (Both settings should be inside a group if it is not the whole document)

Comment: Also, I'd change `\lineskip=0pt` into `\offinterlineskip` and enclose everything in a group.  Though correcting David is definitely outside my competence zone...

Comment: @mbork yes I omitted the group to keep the answer free of clutter at the expense of usability in a real document:-)

Answer (score 6):

Another option, using TikZ and chains:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
start chain=going below,
node distance=3mm,
every node/.style={on chain,join},
every join/.style={-},
block/.style={draw, text width=3cm,align=center}
]
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
  \node[block] {Text \i};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**The Code**:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[auto, 
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width = 6em, align =center},
line/.style = {draw, thick, -}]

\matrix[every node/.style = block, row sep=6mm]{
\node (t1) {Text 1}; \\
\node (t2) {Text 2}; \\
\node (t3) {Text 3}; \\
\node (t4) {Text 4}; \\
};
\path[line] (t1) -- (t2) -- (t3) -- (t4); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

**The Output**:

[image: somefun.png]

Answer (score 1):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\def\mybox#1{\psframebox{\makebox[3cm]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\offinterlineskip
\psmatrix[rowsep=.5]
\mybox{A}\\
\mybox{B}\\
\mybox{C}
\endpsmatrix
\multido{\ia=1+1,\ib=2+1}{3}{\ncline{\ia,1}{\ib,1}}
\end{document}
```