# How to Make This Block Diagram with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I understand that there are some questions here regarding the block diagrams. However, I am strongly interested in one particular style shown as below:

[image]

This is a picture from a paper. As can be seen, the text can be selected there. So it is not an attached picture. I suppose it is done by LaTeX.

**Could anyone point me to the right direction to achieve this?**

(I specially LOVE the colored "thin grid"! It is much more beautiful than the fully filled color!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a start of an answer: later I will come back with more details.

First of all, for element positioning you can refer to [High level digital design in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110209/high-level-digital-design-in-tikz/110260#110260) and [Replicate this chart using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103760/replicate-this-chart-using-latex/103816#103816).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum width=4cm,anchor=south},
font=\small]

% = = = = = = =
% First part

\node[block,text width=3.85cm,align=center](net) at (0,0){Reading of network\\ interfaces and sensors};
%%
\draw[-stealth]($(net.north west)!0.45!(net.north)$)--++(0,0.75)
node[block,minimum width=1.5cm](rec){Recognition};
\draw[-stealth]($(net.north east)!0.45!(net.north)$)--++(0,0.75)
node[block,minimum width=1.5cm](loc){Localization};
%%
\draw[-stealth](rec.north)--++(0,0.75)
node[block,minimum width=1.5cm](sens){Driving Sensing};
%%
\path(net.north)--++(0,3.25)
node[block](lctr){Location and trajectories}; % just for positioning
\draw[-stealth](sens.north)--(sens.north|-lctr.south);
\draw[-stealth](loc.north)--(loc.north|-lctr.south);
%%
\draw[-stealth](lctr.north)--++(0,0.75)
node[block](mb){Mobility model};

% grid
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[yellow!90!red]($(net.south west)-(0.4,0.2)$)
grid[step=1.75pt]($(mb.north east)+(0.4,0.2)$);
\draw($(net.south west)-(0.4,0.2)$)rectangle($(mb.north east)+(0.4,0.2)$);
\end{scope}
\node[below of=net] {Private Phone};

% = = = = = = =
% Second part
\node[block] (carr) at (6.5,0){Carpooling request};
%%
\draw[-stealth](carr.north)--++(0,0.75)
node[block](math){Matching};
%%
\draw[stealth-]($(math.north west)!0.45!(math.north)$)--++(0,0.75)
node[block,minimum width=1.65cm,text width=1.55cm,align=center](tp){Trajectory\\ Prediction};
\draw[stealth-]($(math.north east)!0.45!(math.north)$)--++(0,0.75)
node[block,minimum width=1.65cm,text width=1.55cm,align=center](pe){Position\\ Estimation};
\draw[-stealth](pe)--(tp);
%%
\path(math.north)--++(0,2.25)
node[block](avm){Available vehicle mobility}; % just for positioning
\draw[stealth-](tp.north)--(tp.north|-avm.south);
%%
\draw[stealth-](avm.north)--++(0,0.75)
node[block](vmd){Vehicle mobility database};
% grid
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[blue!60!cyan]($(carr.south west)-(0.4,0.2)$)
grid[step=1.75pt]($(vmd.north east)+(0.4,0.2)$);
\draw($(carr.south west)-(0.4,0.2)$)rectangle($(vmd.north east)+(0.4,0.2)$);
\end{scope}
\node[below of=carr] {Carpooling Server};
% = = = = = = =
% Second part
\begin{scope}[font=\footnotesize]
% 1:
\draw[red,-stealth](mb)--(vmd)node[midway,above,text width=2cm,align=center]{(1) Crowd Sourcing};
% 2: solution that might be improved with the orthopath library
\draw[red,-stealth](sens.east)--++(2,0)|-(avm)node[pos=0.75,below,text width=2cm,align=center]{(2)\\ Activating};
% 3: 
\draw[dashed,red,-stealth](loc.east)--++(1,0)|-(math)node[pos=0.55,below,text width=2cm,align=center]{(3)\\ Correcting};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: OMG, beautiful! It would be the best if you can show me the inter-block red connections there. Thank you so much! Wait for your updates! :)

Comment: There is a missing indent at \end{document}. Unfortunately this can not be fixed with an simple edit, because inserting 4 spaces does not full fill the criterion on "at least 6 characters" to be able to edit it

Comment: @samcarter: right, thanks. It's at the end, but I forgot to apply the markdown. :)

Comment: May I ask you a follow-up question? Say if I have it in my paper, as you can see the code may be quite long, so it may not be very good to just insert the whole block into the words. So is it possible to put it at the the end of the .tex file and give it a label and call it between the words like calling a function in C? Thanks!

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: there's a number of ways to make it. The simplest one I see is to put the code of the diagram in a separate `.tex` file, say `diagram.tex`. Then in you main `.tex` file you will say `\input{diagram.tex}`.

Comment: Owe, so awesome! What if I have multiple such kind of diagrams in my diagram.tex? Can I label every diagram inside, and input only one each time? Oh actually I prefer to put it in the same tex file, because it is easier to circulate with the co-authors. In addition, putting it in one file is easier to get quantities like \columwidth, right? Thanks!

Comment: one follow up question: regarding the grid \begin{scope}[on background layer]. What if I have three layers and wish to draw the grid on 2nd last layer?

Comment: Do not use the `scope` environment, but `pgfonlayer` that allows you to select the layer. See 82 _Layered Graphics_ on the pgfmanual.

Answer (score 6):

My solution uses:

- the `backgrounds` library to place the grid node behind all other nodes,
- the `patterns` library as well as a definition for a `thinner grid` pattern for the grid nodes (there is also a `crosshatch` pattern that would suit the diagram better),
- my [`positioning-plus`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex) library for keys like `west below` and `span vertical`,
- the `fit` library (loaded by `positioning-plus?`) and
- my `paths.ortho` library ([files/origin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/16595)) which is updated including keys like `|*` and `*|` developed originally for [TeXwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1289/vertikale-verbindung-zwischen-zwei-ungleich-groen-elementen/1295).

I opted for a line-break in the `Driving Sensing` node and a higher `Carpooling request` node. I also wouldn’t use that grid background here but maybe just a whitened filling.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,paths.ortho,positioning-plus,patterns}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  @edges to/.code={{{% three braces to protect \pgfeov
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@@edges to/.@cmd}}
                        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@@edges to/.@cmd}[]}#1\pgfeov}}},
  @@edges to/.style args={[#1]#2}{insert path={edge[#1] (#2) (#2)}},
  edges to/.style={@edges to/.list={#1}}}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{thinner grid}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{2pt}{2pt}}
                          {\pgfqpoint{1.5pt}{1.5pt}}{%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.2pt}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{1.55pt}}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.55pt}{0pt}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=+.5cm and +2cm,
  block/.style={align=center, draw, thin, fill=white, shape=rectangle, text depth=+0pt},
  big block/.style={block, minimum width=+4.5cm},
  small block/.style={
    block, minimum width=width("Localization")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})}
]

%% Positioning
% left
\node [big block]                       (Mm) {Mobility model};
\node [big block,   below=     of Mm]   (Lt) {Location and trajectories};
\node [small block, west below=of Lt]   (DS) {Driving\\Sensing};
\node [small block, west below=of DS]   (R)  {Recognition};
\node [big block,   west below=of R] (Rnis) {Readings of network\\interfaced and sensors};
\node [small block, east above=of Rnis] (L)  {Localization};
% right
\node [big block,   right=     of Mm]  (Vmd) {Vehicle mobility database};
\node [big block,   below=     of Vmd] (Avm) {Available vehicle mobility};
\node [small block, west below=of Avm] (TP)  {Trajectory\\Prediction};
\node [small block, east below=of Avm] (PE)  {Position\\estimation};
\node [big block,   west below=of TP]  (M)   {Matching};
\node [big block,   below=     of M,
                 span vertical=Rnis]   (Cr)  {Carpooling request};

%% Connection
% left
\path[->] (Rnis) [edges to={[*|] R, DS, [|*] Lt, Mm}]
          (Rnis) [edges to={[*|] L,     [|*] Lt}]
;
% right
\path[->] (Vmd) [edges to={Avm, [*|] TP, [|*] M, [<-] Cr}]
          (PE) edge (TP) edge[|*] (M);

\begin{scope}[
  on background layer,
  nodes={draw, inner sep=+.6666em, pattern=thinner grid},
  label position=below,
  s/.style n args={3}{ pattern color=#1, fit=#2, label=#3}
]% \hfill\null is only to suppres an underful hbox warning
  \node[s={yellow!80!black}{(Mm)(Rnis)}            {Private phone}]     {\hfill\null};
  \node[s={blue!80!black}  {(Vmd)(Cr|- Rnis.south)}{Carpooling server}] {\hfill\null};
\end{scope}

\path[red, ->, auto,
     nodes={font=\scriptsize, align=center}
  ] (Mm) edge node {(1) Crowd \\ Sourcing}                       (Vmd)
    (L)  edge[dashed] node {(3) \\ Correcting} coordinate (@aux) (M)
    (DS) edge[to path={-| (@aux|-\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}]
              node [at start] {(2) \\ Activating}                (Avm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the latex code, I would recommend using *latexdraw*, an interactive tool in which you can draw your diagram and it will generate the code for you.

https://github.com/arnobl/latexdraw/wiki/Manual