# How can I get these two nested \foreach loops to work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion, loops, foreach

I try to use nested `\foreach` loops to create edges between many nodes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0, 1) {};
  \node (b) at (0, -1) {};
  \node (c) at (1, 0) {};
  \node (d) at (-1, 0) {};
  \foreach \from/\targets in {%
    b/d,%
    {a/b,c,d}%
  } {
    \typeout{\from-\targets}
    \foreach \to in {\targets} {
      \typeout{ \from-\to}
      \path (\from) edge (\to);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this fails with the cryptic error

```
b-d
 b-d
a-b,c,d
 a-b,c,d

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `b' (in 'b').
```

As `\typeout` visible before the error show, seemingly `\targets` is not expanded and thus interpreted a single parameter instead of a list. Can expansion be forced at this point? Or is there another way to fix it?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the parentheses from the inner loop.  Namely, instead of passing `{\targets}` to the `\foreach` loop, you should be passing `\targets`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0, 1) {};
  \node (b) at (0, -1) {};
  \node (c) at (1, 0) {};
  \node (d) at (-1, 0) {};
  \foreach \from/\targets in {%
    b/d,%
    {a/b,c,d}%
  } {
    \typeout{\from-\targets}
    \foreach \to in \targets {
      \typeout{ \from-\to}
      \path (\from) edge (\to);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `\foreach \from/\targets in {b/{d},a/{b,c,d}}...`

Comment: @Jubobs which--what you suggest--is much easier to read and understand. :)  I was just trying to stick with the OP's notation.

Comment: I couldn't make sense of the OP's notation, so I took some liberties :)

Answer (score 4):

Problems with `\foreach` aside, I think the syntax

```
\path (b) edge (d)
      (a) edge (b) edge (c) edge (d);
```

comes much more natural. It is also much easier to change edge options on an edge-to-edge basis (or for more than one edge, too):

```
\path (b) edge (d) {[thick]
      (a) edge (b) edge[green] (c) edge[red,->] (d)};
```

Though, a similar thing can still be done with `\foreach`, say

```
\path (b) edge (d) {[thick]
      (a) \foreach \opt/\p in {/b, green/c, {red,->}/d}
                  {edge[style/.expand once=\opt] (\p)}};
```

With my [qrr.misc](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibraryqrr.misc.code.tex) library (code similar to the keys in [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132939/16595)), one can do

```
\path (b) edge (d) {[thick]
      (a) [edges to={b,[green] c, [{red,->}] d}]};
```

It should be noted that the `,` in the options has to be protected somehow, either in that way shown or by doing `{[red, ->] d}`, i.e. enclosing the whole thing in braces. (This could be made more robust or can be changed to use `(` and `)` around the coordinates instead of using `,`, but the implementation will need more parsing then.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{qrr.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0, 1) {};  \node (b) at (0, -1) {};
  \node (c) at (1, 0) {};  \node (d) at (-1, 0) {};
  \path (b) edge (d) {[thick]
        (a) edge (b) edge[green] (c) edge[red,->] (d)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0, 1) {};  \node (b) at (0, -1) {};
  \node (c) at (1, 0) {};  \node (d) at (-1, 0) {};
  \path (b) edge (d) {[thick]
        (a) \foreach \opt/\p in {/b, green/c, {red,->}/d}
                    {edge[style/.expand once=\opt] (\p)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0, 1) {};  \node (b) at (0, -1) {};
  \node (c) at (1, 0) {};  \node (d) at (-1, 0) {};
  \path (b) edge (d) {[thick]
        (a) [edges to={b,[green] c, [{red,->}] d}]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is to be consistent in the way you specify elements in a list to be processed by `\foreach`.

In the approach below, which I find more intuitive, `\targets` gets expanded to `{b}` at the first iteration of the outer loop, and to `{b,c,d}` at the second one. Therefore, specifying `\foreach \to in \targets` for the inner loop works as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0, 1) {};
  \node (b) at (0, -1) {};
  \node (c) at (1, 0) {};
  \node (d) at (-1, 0) {};
  \foreach \from/\targets in {b/{d},a/{b,c,d}}
  {%
    \typeout{\from-\targets}
    \foreach \to in \targets
    {%
        \typeout{ \from-\to}
      \path (\from) edge (\to);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```