# Drawing a block diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would really like to create multiple variations on the image attached. Even a basic template to get me started would be great.[image]

Comment: see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: A simple google search for "tikz block diagram" basically gives you everything you need http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/

Comment: Also, check out all the Related questions listed to the right.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132897/how-to-make-this-block-diagram-with-latex might especially be helpful.  I like the way he put some of the rectangles in the background layer.

Answer (score 4):

Tips to get it done:

- define a style for nodes with rectangle border and without (you may tune them)
- use a `matrix of nodes` for positioning the nodes, as they are fitting to a grid
- in the matrix you can apply styles by: `... & |[stylename]| text & ...`
- after the matrix, draw arrows referring to implicit matrix node names, such as `\draw[->] (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)`
- for the outer rectangles, use the `fit` library with a rounded rectangle node shape