# How to draw the following border outlines using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I have drawn the boxes A to F and the arrows. What I do not know is how to draw the two outer blocks - block1 covering blocks A to D and block2 covering E and F. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example, so we could help you easier

Comment: You can also have a look to [How to Make This Block Diagram with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132897/13304).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the TikZ `fit` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {
    draw,rounded corners,
    minimum width=3cm
  }]
  \node             (A) {A};
  \node[below of=A] (B) {B};
  \node[below of=B] (C) {C};
  \node[below of=C] (D) {D};
  \node[below of=D] (E) {E};
  \node[below of=E] (F) {F};

  \draw (A) edge[->] (B);
  \draw (B) edge[->] (C);
  \draw (C) edge[->] (D);
  \draw (D) edge[->] (E);
  \draw (E) edge[->] (F);

  \node[fit=(A) (B) (C) (D)] {};
  \node[fit=(E) (F)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: For the record, you don't need to specify the middle nodes (B and C) in the `fit` command. The "extremes" are enough, so the first one can be reduced to: `\node[fit=(A) (D)] {};` :)