# How to Make a specific Block Diagram with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I understand that there are some questions here regarding the block diagrams. However, I am strongly interested in one particular style shown as below:

[image]

I found it in a thesis. Most likely it is drawn by PowerPoint. But I am wondering can it be created by latex.

**Could anyone point me to the right direction to achieve this?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Sometimes, the [Related menu on the right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132897/how-to-make-this-block-diagram-with-latex?rq=1) gives answer that may help.

Comment: That's normal biz with tikz, though you need to learn a little. // A good starting point is the Minimal introduction: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . Once digested, use the big manual to find details and more possibilities. // See this tutorial https://latexdraw.com/block-diagram-in-latex-step-by-step-tikz-tutorial/ or the tikz gallery for inspiration https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/ . // Try the tag search here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf , e.g. combined with further search terms. // Start small, build slowly.