# How to create this diagram with boxes and arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How to create this diagram with boxes and arrow ?
Thanks a lot.
[image: How to create this diagram with boxes and arrow ?]

Comment: Could you post some code showing your efforts so far? Then others will be able to help with the parts that are causing problems for you.

Comment: @IanThompson is right, please show some effort. You might want to have a look [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/assignment-structure/)

Comment: You might be interested in [Replicate this chart using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103760/13304).

Answer (score 4):

This is an attempt where `matrix of nodes` is used. The text may need some corrections because some of them are hard to read.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows,calc, positioning}

\begin{document}    
%\begin{figure}
%\begin{center}
\tikzset{%
blockA/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=6cm, align=left, rounded corners, minimum height=6.2cm,minimum width=6cm},
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=6cm, align=left, rounded corners, minimum height=4em,minimum width=6cm},
line/.style = {draw, -stealth},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
% Place nodes with matrix nodes
 \matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]{%
\node [blockA] (n1) {Field Tapes and observers log\\
(1) Pre processing\\
\begin{itemize}
\item De .... can not read
\item Reformatting
\item Editting
\item Geometric spreading
\item Setup of field Geometry
\item Application of field statics
\end{itemize}};
& \node [block] (n8) {DMO Correction};
\node [block,below=1cm of n8] (n9) {Inverse NMO Correction};
\node [block,below=1cm of n9] (n10) {Velocity Analysis}; \\
\node [block] (n2) {(2) Deconvolution and Trace };   
&\node [block] (n11) {NMO correction};\\
\node [block] (n3) {(3) cmp sorting};                 
& \node [block] (n12) {Deconvolution};\\
\node [block] (n4) {(4) velocity analysis};              
& \node [block] (n13) {Time-variant spectrum Whitening};   \\
\node [block] (n5) {(5) Residual statics corrections}; 
&\node [block] (n14) {Time-variant Filtering};     \\
\node [block] (n6) {(6) Velocity Analysis};                                          
& \node [block] (n15) {Migration};   \\
\node [block] (n7) {(7) NMO Correction};                                           
& \node [block] (n16) {Gain Application};\\
};
% Draw edges
\foreach \i/\j in {1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/7}{
  \path [line] (n\i) -- (n\j);}

\foreach \i/\j in {8/9,9/10,10/11,11/12,12/13,13/14,14/15,15/16}
    \path [line] (n\i) -- (n\j);

\path [line] (n7.east) -- ++(0.5cm,0)coordinate(a) -- (a |- n8.north)-- ++(0,0.5cm) -| (n8.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```