# Tikz flow chart questions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am totally new to the package tikz but I am going to make a flow chart for my poster. I used the template provided by this [link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/assignment-structure/)

I just modify some parts I can understand and the source code is

```
                % Author: Rasmus Pank Roulund
    \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
            decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
            matrix,shapes.symbols}

    \tikzset{
    >=stealth',
        punktchain/.style={
            rectangle, 
            rounded corners, 
            % fill=black!10,
            draw=black, very thick,
            text width=10em, 
            minimum height=3em, 
            text centered, 
            on chain},
        line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
        element/.style={
            tape,
            top color=white,
            bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
            minimum width=8em,
            draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
            text width=10em, 
            minimum height=3.5em, 
            text centered, 
            on chain},
        every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
        decoration={brace},
        tuborg/.style={decorate},
        tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [node distance=.8cm,
        start chain=going below,]
             \node[punktchain, join] (intro) {Raw Signal};
             \node[punktchain, join] (probf)      {Pre-pro1};
             \node[punktchain, join] (investeringer)      {pre-pro2};
             \node[punktchain, join] (perfekt) {feature extract};
             \node[punktchain, join, ] (emperi) {model fitting};

  \node[punktchain, join,] (disk) {training};
        \node[punktchain, join,] (makro) {testing};
        \node (asym) [punktchain ]  {Abnormal};

                \begin{scope}[start branch=venstre,
                    %We need to redefine the join-style to have the -> turn out right
                    every join/.style={-, thick, shorten <=1pt}, ]
                \end{scope}
                \begin{scope}[start branch=hoejre,]
                \node (finans) [punktchain, on chain=going right] {Normal };
             \end{scope}

        % Now that we have finished the main figure let us add some "after-drawings"
        %% First, let us connect (finans) with (disk). We want it to have
        %% square corners.
        %\draw[|-,-|,->, thick,] (finans.south) |-+(0,-1em)-| (disk.north);
        % Now, let us add some braches. 
        %% No. 1

        %% No. 2
        \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(disk.north), \p2=(makro.south) in
            ($(2, \y1)$) -- ($(2, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {Classification};
        %% No. 3
        \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(perfekt.north), \p2=(emperi.south) in
            ($(2, \y1)$) -- ($(2, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {Feature Selection};
            \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(probf.north), \p2=(investeringer.south) in
            ($(2, \y1)$) -- ($(2, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {Data Preprocessing};

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
    %%% Local Variables: 
    %%% mode: latex
    %%% TeX-master: t
    %%% End:
```

And the output is [image]

Here are something I would like;

1. Centered the two boxes (normal) (abnormal)
2. Arrows from the upper boxes to (normal) and (abnormal)
3. Place box (training) and (testing) horizontally without arrow.
4. Other suggestions make it look professional: like color ...

I draw a picture by hands to make my idea clear. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to mock up a picture of what you want? Say, using MS Paint? Or even hand-drawn and then scanned in? It would clarify your intentions and make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @JohnWickerson Good idea. I made one hand-drawn and hope it helps.

Comment: I think combining some hints from [TikZ arrow positioning](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56888/13304) and some others from [how to draw a process flow figure?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66939/13304) you can made it better. If your really want to use chains, then also [Draw a multi-chain structure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63063/13304) is of help.

Comment: this example looks quite close to what you want: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labs-schema/

Comment: Please use more concrete subject.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to do something similar myself so it was a good exercise.

Tikz experts will find more elegant code I'm sure, but
based on the example http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labs-schema/ this is what I've achieved:
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,positioning}
% Define the layers to draw the diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{materia}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=6.0em, text centered,
  minimum height=1.5em,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{etape} = [materia, text width=8em, minimum width=10em,
  minimum height=3em, rounded corners, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{texto} = [above, text width=6em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{linepart} = [draw, thick, color=black!50, -latex', dashed]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, color=black!50, -latex']
\tikzstyle{ur}=[draw, text centered, minimum height=0.01em]

% Define distances for bordering
\newcommand{\blockdist}{1.3}
\newcommand{\edgedist}{1.5}

\newcommand{\etape}[2]{node (p#1) [etape]
  {#2}}

% Draw background
\newcommand{\background}[5]{%
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    % Left-top corner of the background rectangle
    \path (#1.west |- #2.north)+(-0.5,0.25) node (a1) {};
    % Right-bottom corner of the background rectanle
    \path (#3.east |- #4.south)+(+0.5,-0.25) node (a2) {};
    % Draw the background
    \path[fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed]
      (a1) rectangle (a2);
      \path (#3.east |- #2.north)+(0,0.25)--(#1.west |- #2.north) node[midway] (#5-n) {};
      \path (#3.east |- #2.south)+(0,-0.35)--(#1.west |- #2.south) node[midway] (#5-s) {};
      \path (#3.east |- #2.north)+(0.7,0)--(#3.east |- #4.south) node[midway] (#5-w) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}}

\newcommand{\transreceptor}[3]{%
  \path [linepart] (#1.east) -- node [above]
    {\scriptsize #2} (#3);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,transform shape]

  % Draw diagram elements
  \path \etape{1}{Raw signal};

  \path (p1.south)+(0.0,-1.5) \etape{2}{Pre-1};
  \path (p2.south)+(0.0,-1.0) \etape{3}{Pre-2};

  \path (p3.south)+(0.0,-1.5) \etape{4}{Feature extract};
  \path (p4.south)+(0.0,-1.0) \etape{5}{Model fitting};

  \path (p5.south)+(-3.0,-2.0) \etape{6}{training};
  \path (p5.south)+(3.0,-2.0) \etape{7}{testing};
  \node [below=of p5] (p6-7) {};

  \path (p6.south)+(0.0,-2.0) \etape{8}{normal};
  \path (p7.south)+(0.0,-2.0) \etape{9}{abnormal};
  \node [below=of p6-7] (p8-9) {};

  % Draw arrows between elements
  \path [line] (p1.south) -- node [above] {} (p2);
  \path [line] (p2.south) -- node [above] {} (p3);
  \path [line] (p3.south) -- node [above] {} (p4);
  \path [line] (p4.south) -- node [above] {} (p5);

  \background{p2}{p2}{p3}{p3}{bk1}
  \background{p4}{p4}{p5}{p5}{bk2}
  \background{p6}{p6}{p7}{p7}{bk3}

  \path [line] (p5.south) -- node [above] {} (bk3-n);
  \path [line] (bk3-s) -- node [above] {} (p8);
  \path [line] (bk3-s) -- node [above] {} (p9);
  \path (bk1-w)+(+6.0,0) node (ur1)[ur] {};
  \path (bk2-w)+(+6.0,0) node (ur2)[ur] {};
  \path (bk3-w)+(+3.0,0) node (ur3)[ur] {};
  \transreceptor{bk1-w}{pre processing}{ur1};
  \transreceptor{bk2-w}{Feature selection}{ur2};
  \transreceptor{bk3-w}{classification}{ur3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I drop the small squares on the right and make the dashed arrows to be dashed lines.

Comment: sure, just drop the ur in \path (bk1-w)+(+6.0,0) node (ur1)[ur] {}; replace by \path (bk1-w)+(+6.0,0) node (ur1)[] {}; this is the node decoration. don't understand what you mean with dashed arrow.

Comment: You can also have the text at the end of arrow by \path (bk1-w)+(+6.0,0) node (ur1)[] {Pre process}; an remove the other text.